# CloudBees XML Config vs Command-Line Tool

Tags: java, config, web.xml, cloudbees, paas

I see that CloudBees allows apps to be deployed with a `cloudbees-web.xml` descriptor, however on the page in the developer docs [that describes this descriptor](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/CloudBeesWebXml), it says:

> The `cloudbees-web.xml` is considered "legacy" - it is not deprecated (yet) - and we don't currently have a plan to get rid of it - but it is the less preferred way to manage environment settings.

This prompts two questions:

1. Is `cloudbees-web.xml` the *only* CloudBees-specific config file that apps can deploy with, or are there others? If so, what are they and where is their documentation? (For instance, GAE allows you to deploy your apps with `cron.xml`, `dos.xml`, `queues.xml`, etc...).
2. Can the CloudBees SDK accomplish *everything* (via Configuration Parameters) that `cloudbees-web.xml` does, or is there functionality that only `cloudbees-web.xml` can do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cloudbees-web.xml is indeed legacy configuration mechanism, and is superseded by resources binding and configuration parameters
All cloudbees-web.xml features are fully available using SDK, the later does actually offer far more options than cloudbees-web.xml.

Cloudbees don't uses any other vendor specific descriptor. We try to keep the platform rely on JavaEE API and de-facto standards.

Comment: **This is not true** - there *are* certain things you can only do in `cloudbees-web.xml` that you *cannot* do with the command-line tool (SDK). One such thing is in setting custom mail sessions as described [here](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/SendGrid). You can't do that with the SDK.